# Where can I get a windows binary install for Python 3.4 or 3.5?

Tags: python, legacy

Where can I get hold of Python for Windows Release 3.4 or 3.5? I'm hoping that will let me use py2exe to package up a little game I wrote as an exe. (Apparently Release 3.6 changed the 'bytecode' structure such that py2exe will no longer work.. )
The python.org site only hosts installable binaries for the latest version.  Thanks for helping me out here.

EDIT: I've put 3.4 and 3.5 in the question title to underline what is in the text above.  Plus, to stress: I'm looking for binary installable packages.

Comment: You have a lot of versions here: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Consider PyInstaller instead - https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: Specifically looking for an install i.e. binary not sources.

Comment: Thanks Alastair, worth a look there.

Comment: python 3.5 https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/

Comment: Thanks Alastair, I checked that out, it works and obviates the need to revert my python installation (not easy anyhow given the binaries are gone).

Comment: Thanks dangee.. the python site seems to have decided to keep only the initial version of older releases, instead of the last version of older releases. I'd've thought the last version of older releases (being the least buggy) would be what they would preserve, but that logic tripped me up when I went hunting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here they are:

- Python 3.4: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-340/
- Python 3.5: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks I've edited your answer to include those and accepted it.

Answer (score 3):

I'll put this 'answer' for anyone else who's also been trying to build an executable from their python script, and thinks that they need py2exe + Python 3.4/3.5 :-

ElBaulP pointed out the older binary installs of old Python I requested - seems they are only available for the INITIAL major releases (3.4.0 and 3.5.0 ); see ElBaulP's answer.

(But, according to Alastair McCormack's comment, you can avoid the py2exe+older python headache and use [pyinstaller.org](https://pyinstaller.org) with a 3.7 release.. I tested this works for my little tkinter-based GUI).